# Newly deployed ASP.net web application returns "This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!" error message

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I've handed my ASP.net 2.0 web application over to the System Admin for deployment to IIS 6.0 and when I hit the site I get the message:

> This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!

This is not a precompiled web application.

peace | dewde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been told that the web.config file was missing. Adding it back resolved the issue. Also, it turns out the web app was deployed via the Visual Studio IDE "Publish" mechanism. So that may explain the precompiled status.

peace | dewde